# Catching "assignment inside conditional" bugs in PHP

Tags: php

We just had a problem with a piece of code that accidentally assigned a variable in a condition, of this shape: `if ($type = 'foozle')` (That's = instead of ==). It's an easy mistake to make, and if it had been enabled, we would even have gotten a PhpStorm warning for it.

What I would like is an automated pre-commit hook that checks for this kind of problem. Since I cannot run the PhpStorm checks from a script (that would be awesome, because it has tons of good checks), I'm looking for another tool that can analyze the code. I've looked at PHP CodeSniffer, PHP Mess Detector, and etsy/phan, but none of them warn about this particular kind of bug, at least not out of the box. Am I missing any big names here, or are there configuration options that would add this check to any of the ones I have already tried?

Comment: `if ($type = 'foozle')` is valid PHP, so tools like CodeSniffer and Mess Detector won't pick up on it.

Comment: Surely this should show up in testing.... A phase that should come before commiting code

Comment: I know that it's valid PHP, but it's more often wrong than right. Which is why C compilers warn about it, and PhpStorm has an inspection for it. I want to see a tool give me a warning.

Comment: Yes, this would come up in testing, if all code paths had tests. Which in this case, they did not (legacy code). Up until a recent change, $type == 'foozle' was always true, and this code only started breaking when a second type was introduced.

Comment: Can' t you use the svn configuration for pre-commit hooks?

Comment: create your own code sniffer rule: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php